# Google api not authorizing for site on test server, but working on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm having a problem with my site that uses google drive API that only affects the test server we have it on, but not localhost where I am testing it. As you can imagine this makes it hard to troubleshoot. After writing to a text file as the program runs I managed to find the exact statement causing the issues:

```
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                null).Result;
```

Which leads me to believe the error has something to do with permissions/authorization. My localhost and test site permissions are exactly the same on the google api console, and this is where I get my client secrets from.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgobZ.png

Above 44354 is my localhost and the blacked out http (not https) url is our test server.
As you can see the origins and redirect uris are exactly the same, so I can't figure out why it would work on one and not the other.

This is the statement stream comes from:

```
var stream = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```

EDIT: I just realized the test server is actually the http address, not the https address. Could this be why? Do google API calls not work over http?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/FAQ.md#can-i-use-googlewebauthorizationbroker-on-a-server

Comment: (Basically, `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroken` isn't the class you're looking for. You should be using the https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc package.

Comment: Thank you guys. GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker is what was used in the examples I read so I used it here as well.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the server equivalent is? I tried using GoogleCredential but it refuses to use my client_secrets to make a credential

Comment: I said - you want Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc

Comment: (Assuming you want to authenticate as a user rather than with service credentials.)

Comment: I know, but it didn't work the same way and was thus confusing. I figured it out eventually though, I'll post my answer

Comment: Well it's not the same way, no - because there's obviously a difference between starting a browser locally and serving the login pages to a user remotely.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out through much trial and error.

I had to add this piece of code:

```
            GoogleClientSecrets cs = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream);

            flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = cs.Secrets.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = cs.Secrets.ClientSecret
                },
                Scopes = Scopes,
            });
```

And then get a token. To get the token I followed the instructions here, under OAuth Playground: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication

And then used the information there to make this:

```
        TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse
        {
            RefreshToken = "refreshtokenhere",
            TokenType = "Bearer",
            ExpiresInSeconds = 3600
        };
```

(I don't think the tokentype or expires in are important, but I included them anyway)

And finally:

```
credential = new UserCredential(flow, "me", token);
```

Then this credential was used in the same way as before.